# Why node.js can call clustet.fork() inside of the if statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multiprocess

For a typical C program, we do something like this to create a new process:

```
int main(void)
{
    pid_t childPID;

    childPID = fork();

   if(childPID >0){
       do something
   }
   else if(childPID == 0){
        do something
   }
   else {
        do something
   }
}
```

but in a node.js program, the fork is usually done in the if statement:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    do something
    cluster.fork()
}
else{
    do something for the child process
}
```

Why we can create child processes in the if statement in Node.js? Why does not the child process skip the else block?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume this is because `cluster.fork` causes the child processes to execute from the top of the program (unlike C's `fork` which causes execution starting from the next line after the `fork()`), but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 4):

It's because C `fork()` and node.js `cluster.fork()` work in a different way.

In C `fork()` creates an exact duplicate of a current process (except for the `fork()` returned value) and then continue execution of both processes from the point when `fork()` was called.

In node.js `cluster.fork()` spawns new worker node.js process with the same `.js` entry point, but using somewhat different environment. It also establishes an [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) channel for passing messages/file descriptors between master process and its workers.

Comment: So do you mean that the child process executes from the top of the program as @apsillers says?

Comment: Yes, because `cluster.fork()` uses [`child_process.fork()` function](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) to spawn another node.js instance. It's not cloning current process, like C does, it spawns a brand new one.